# Neo4j Cypher results as JSON: Getting JsonMappingException when using JsonHelper.createJsonFrom() but only with certain queries

Tags: java, neo4j, jackson, vert.x

I'm working on neo4vertx, a module that makes it possible to talk to a Neo4j database using Vert.x. Specifically, I'm working on feature called "query" which allows a Vert.x user
to send a Cypher query as an eventbus message and get a JSON resultset back.

However, I seem to run into an unexpected problem when serializing to JSON using JsonHelper.createJsonFrom() with certain queries.

A quick example (database has stuff in it of course):

```
// This Fails with JsonMappingException (see below):
String query="MATCH (n) RETURN n";

// This Succeeds:
String query="MATCH (n) RETURN n.something";

//Rest of code:
engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDatabaseService);
ExecutionResult result;
result = engine.execute(query);

Object object = result.iterator();
String foo = JsonHelper.createJsonFrom(object);
System.out.println("DEBUG (foo): " + foo);
```

Does this look familiar to anyone? We essentially want to be able to
send any kind of query and either return an empty json string or a json
representation not unlike the result.json that you can retrieve from the
web interface of neo4j!

### The Exception:

```
testQuery(org.openpcf.neo4vertx.neo4j.Neo4jGraphTest)  Time elapsed: 2.362 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.neo4j.server.rest.domain.JsonBuildRuntimeException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase$DependencyResolverImpl and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: scala.collection.convert.MapWrapper["content"]->org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy["graphDatabase"]->org.neo4j.test.["dependencyResolver"])

...
```

Comment: The solution is in the exception **to avoid exception, disable `SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS`**. You should be able to configure the feature on your `ObjectMapper`

Comment: This will avoid the exception, but we don't understand why the object is empty in the first place (we're not even sure it is empty). Both queries via the web interface of neo4j *do* return data.

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with the query. Can you print out the `object` and make sure you're getting the expected result? If Jackson is getting the correct object and thinking it's empty, that a whole different type of bug.

Answer (score 0):

Although the ExecutionResult is an implementation of `Iterator<Map<String,Object>>` it is currently just a java wrapper around scala classes, as well as Neo4j classes (like Node, Relationship, Path).

So you have probably to do 2 things:

1. recursively replace neo4j classes with appropriate maps and lists
2. probably: recursively replace scala lists and maps with java lists and maps, e.g. `new LinkedHashMap(row)`

I did some of that some time ago here in my [cypher-websocket-experiments](https://github.com/jexp/cypher_websocket_endpoint/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/remoting/msgpack/ExecutionResultMessagePack.java#L132)

Comment: Hi Michael, We figured it would be something like this; is the default cypher rest interface of neo4j actually doing this? for the time being we've switched to using the rest interface; this way we would avoid possible strangeness and automatically remain compatible with both the cypher json request format and the response format.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the ExecutionResult of Neo4J to JSON this way:

```
ExecutionResult result ...
CypherResultRepresentation repr = new CypherResultRepresentation(result, false, false);
OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(new JsonFormat(), null, null);
String json = format.assemble(repr);
```

The next thing you have to do is to create the appropriate vert.x JsonObject objects.

@Rubin: I'm currently adding this to neo4vertx ;)

Answer (score 0):

By using RESTAPI:

```
String query = "MATCH (a)-[r]-(b) RETURN a,r,b";
RestAPI restAPI = new RestAPIFacade(URI);
CypherResult result = restAPI.query(query, Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
String stringResult = gson.toJson(result.asMap());
JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(stringResult);
```

By using Bolt

```
    String query = "MATCH (a)-[r]-(b) RETURN a,r,b";
String stringConnection = "bolt://" + HOST + ":7687";
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(stringConnection, AuthTokens.basic(USER, PASS));
Session session = driver.session();
StatementResult result = session.run(query);
session.close();
driver.close();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
while (result.hasNext()) {
    Record record = result.next();
    stringResult = gson.toJson(record.asMap());
}
JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(stringResult);
```